# <In> overrides everything else in SharePoint CAML query

Tags: caml-query, caml

I'm writing a CAML query for SharePoint. The list contains a term set field. I want to get all list items having specific terms, plus items where no term is set. My query contains this:

```
<Or>
    <In>
        <FieldRef Name='MyTaxonomyField' /> 
        <Values> 
            <Value Type='Integer'>1</Value> 
            <Value Type='Integer'>2</Value> 
        </Values>
    </In>
    <IsNull>
        <FieldRef Name='MyTaxonomyField'/>
    </IsNull>
</Or>
```

The `<In>` clause gets all items with specific terms. `<IsNull>` gets all items without any terms. Individually both of these work. Put together like this they do not: Only the items with defined terms are returned (i.e. the `<In>` clause runs)

The order does not matter. Changing `<IsNull>` to something else gives similar results. `<In>` appears to override everything else (runs first?). Is this a knowns problem? Is there any solution except for exchanging `<In>` for a bunch of `<Or>` clauses?

Comment: I recognize this behavior. Sadly the only workaround I have is replacing with nested OR-s

Comment: Is it perhaps possible to use <In> to select null values too?

Comment: Not quite sure how one could do that?